# Validate that string is relative url not working

Tags: c#, uri, url-validation

I'm trying to validate that a string representing a url is relative, but it seems `Uri.TryCreate()` will accept any url without the protocol as being relative (ie: www.domain.com/something/else.aspx). But I only need /something/else.aspx/

For example, this test string will always throw an exception when trying to get `uri.PathAndQuery` on line 9. Even though `TryCreate()` returns true.

```
string test = "/something/else.aspx";
bool isValid;
var url = getPathAndQuery(test, out isValid);

private string getPathAndQuery(string url, out bool isValid) {
    Uri uri;
    isValid = Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Relative, out uri);
    try {
        return isValid ? uri.PathAndQuery : string.Empty;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isValid = false;
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Example input/output:

> input: /something/else.aspx ==> output: /something/else.aspx
>
> input: www.domain.com/something/else.aspx ==> output: /something/else.aspx
>
> input: http://www.domain.com/something/else.aspx ==> ouput: string.Empty

**Given the relative path of a url, how can I validate that it is indeed relative and just get the path and query in case the user has also passed the domain?**

Comment: it's easy enough to validate if it's relative, but getting just the path and query of a url that may contain the domain is a bit harder. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you include some example inputs and expected outputs? If the path is relative, how much of the path should be returned?

Answer (score 0):

The path returned by `PathAndQuery` is [always an absolute path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery(v=vs.110).aspx), so it doesn't work for relative paths.

Comment: But the question is how to ensure that is an absolute path before using `PathAndQuery`. I assume that `IsAbsoluteUri` helps.

Comment: It will never be absolute. The whole purpose is to only allow relative urls.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you can't get a full path from a relative url, since it is only possible to get the full path once the relative url has been combined with a base url.

Comment: perhaps regex is the way to go

Comment: What is it about the relative urls that you'd like to check? That there is no http:// at the start for example?